# NsMutableArray and NSOperationQueue

Tags: ios, rest, nsmutablearray, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperationqueue

I'm developing client-server REST app. The architecture is as follows. From UIViewController I always call **Manager** object that contains static arrays of models for populating, let's say, UITableView. Manager calles static procedure of **API_WRAPPER** class, that returns **NSDictionary** object via protocol back to **Manager**. Than , manager creates models from dictionary and notifies UI. There are getters in manager to make static arrays of models visible. All models also can be stored in files via **NSCoding** protocol.

So, this approach with GCD has always been working great, but at my last project synchronization problems appeared - different read-write operations ( deleting some models when sync data with server or inserting some while uploading new ones ) started crashing app with **collection was mutated while enumerating** error. How can I improve my architecture to fix this? Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to have exclusive access to the dictionary or any containers.

For example, this class helps you to avoid the crash.

- https://github.com/mrRay/vvopensource/blob/master/VVBasics/src/MutLockDict.h
- https://github.com/mrRay/vvopensource/blob/master/VVBasics/src/MutLockDict.m

  > This class exists because NSMutableDictionary is not thread-safe by default: if you call methods on it from two different threads at the same time, it will try to execute both, often crashing in the process.  This class has methods which allow you to work with a mutable dictionary in a transparent and thread-safe manner.

The exclusive access is better than using just one giant lock for read/write because the class uses [pthread_rwlock](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/pthread_rwlock_init.3.html). It's more efficient for read access.